# what is atomic exchange (between a register and a memory location) instruction?

Tags: operating-system

I'm studying OS and suddenly curious about what atomic exchange (between a register and a memory location) instruction is. And How it can be used to implement a lock?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean by an atomic exchange but maybe you mean the Compare and swap instruction.

1. A compare and swap instruction checks a memory location for a given value and if the value in that memory location is equal to the given value it sets the memory location to a new value. This is done "atomically" which means that while this instruction executes nothing else can execute in the system (let's keep it that way) or the execution of this instruction can't be preempted. The code for this would look something like this -

```
function cas(p : pointer to int, old : int, new : int) returns bool {
    if *p ≠ old {
        return false
    }
    *p ← new
    return true
}
```

Why is this important from a locking standpoint? Well suppose you have a mutex "lock" and two threads want to access the lock, each thread needs to check if the mutex value is 1 and if it is 1 then the thread must set it to 0. If thread 1 and thread 2 both try to perform this operation at the same time then for the case where the instruction is not atomic both thread 1 might see the value as 1. Thread 1 would try and set the value to 0 but before it reaches that statement it gets pre-empted, thread 2 then sets the value to 0 and then thread 1 sets it again. Both threads can then acquire the lock thinking they are the only ones to have acquired it, which is indeed incorrect behavior.

But if the compare and swap is atomic means that if a thread is inside the cas function depicted above, no other thread will execute until it is done with the complete execution of the function or the execution is guaranteed to finish in 1 cycle. Thus thread1 will update the value of the memory location to 0 and then thread 2 will return false.

Answer (score 1):

An atomic exchange instruction (for example, x86 xchg) stores the specified value into the specified location in memory and places the overwritten value into a register.  In C/C++ and in the Linux kernel, primitives based on this machine instruction pass back the overwritten value as their return value.